# I smelled an organic chemical in a lab. (Hexamethylenediamine) Will it cause brain damage?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Our teacher told us to keep a distance while smelling organic chemicals. I forgot and smelled from the opening of the tiny container. Can this substance be corrosive and may that have neurological implications? Could it have had an effect on my brain (i.e death of brain cells)?

Answer (score 4):

The Material Safety Data Sheet for hexamethylenediamine is here [MSDS here](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9924250).
The main danger is associated with skin or eye contact. If you did not feel any immediate effects from smelling the sample then it is highly unlikely that any lasting harm was done. Take this as a lesson to be very careful when handling chemicals.